# Как сделать ЛИМИТ пользователей в голосовом канале discord.py

Tags: python, discord.py, discord

Как сделать ЛИМИТ пользователей в голосовом канале discord.py
Как на скриншоте:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: Лимит пользователей в голосовом канале

Comment: что не понятно.

Comment: https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/941775310460960809/942026492714549308/unknown.png

Answer (score 2):

Кому надо:

```
await bot.get_channel(CHANNEL_ID).edit(user_limit = CHANNEL_LIMIT)
```